# Most general function which is independent of variable y

Tags: calculus

I have come to the point where the functions 
$$G(x,y) G(y,z)$$ must be independent of y. The books then state that the most general function $G(x,y)$ with this property is

$G(x,y)=\frac{r H(x)}{H(y)}$, where r is a constant.

Now Im not sure how we can say that this is independet of y since it is a function that takes a variable y? Could someone please take the time to explain?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$G$ is not independent of $y$, but the product $G(x, y)G(y, z)$ is. This can be easily seen by just plugging in the definition of $G$:
$$G(x, y)G(y, z) = \frac{rH(x)}{H(y)} \frac{rH(y)}{H(z)} = r^2\frac{H(x)}{H(z)}$$

Comment: Thank you! That makes sense:)